# Next/Prev button not work when using slickGoTo

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag, slick.js

I'm using the Slick slider in my website and when I try to use the `slickGoTo` function, I see an issue. `slickGoTo` works perfectly, but after I use it, my next/prev buttons and also the drag for changing slides does not work at all.

What must I do to fix this issue?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.calendar_slide .rail ul').slick({
        dots: false,
        infinite: false,
        draggable: true,
        speed: 300,
        slidesToShow: 10,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        nextArrow: '.arrow_prev',
        prevArrow: '.arrow_next',
        rtl: true
    });
    $('.calendar_slide .rail ul').slick('slickGoTo', 38);
});
```

When I set the `infinite` option to `true`, the issue is fixed. However, I don't want to use the `infinite` mode.

Comment: do you get an error in console? can you describe more what the issue is? (it's hard to have an answer for: "it does not work at all")